# estilos de css modules no cargan a volver a la pagina anterior

Tags: css, reactjs, nextjs

Estoy usando next js con rutas paralelas y rutas interceptadas para mostrar un modal,tambien uso next/Link para cambiar entre rutas
[image: Los estilos se aplican correctamente]

Aqui carga el modal correctamente
[image: Aqui carga el modal correctamente]

Recargo la pagina y me redirige a la ruta interceptada como debe de ser
[image]

Y este es el problema, cuando voy al enlace de shop, que me redirige  a la ruta de /products, la cual es la pagina de la primer imagen donde muestra todos los productos no carga correctamente los estilos
[image: problema]

Como puede ver los estilos no se aplican pero si aparecen los nombres de clase sin estilos
[image: no cargan los estilos pero si los nombres de clase]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.